# OData routing cannot find the route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, .net-5

This is my `ApplicationUserController` (I removed unneccessary parts like ctor etc):

```cs
[ODataRouting]
public class ApplicationUserController : ApiController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("ApplicationUser")]
    [HttpGet("ApplicationUser/$count")]
    public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Get()
    {
        return _applicationUserRepository.GetQueryable();
    }

    [HttpGet("ApplicationUser/{id}")]
    [HttpGet("ApplicationUser({id})")]
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetById([FromODataUri] long id)
    {
        return await _applicationUserRepository.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

The first function works perfectly. I call `http://localhost:5000/v1/ApplicationUser?$filter=startsWith(LastName, 'Test')` and I get all user that last name starts with "Test".

The second one doesn't work. I call

- `http://localhost:5000/v1/ApplicationUser/1`
- `http://localhost:5000/v1/ApplicationUser(1)`

and none of them do work. For both, I get a 404: Not found.

Is there something I did wrong?
I also tried adding the `EnableQuery`-Attribute, but it doesn't make any difference.

Here my code from `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IEdmModel v1 = _getEdmModel();
    
    services.AddOData(opt => opt
        .AddModel("v{version}", v1)
        .Select()
        .Expand()
        .OrderBy()
        .Filter()
        .Count()
    );
}
```

and my `_getEdmModel()`:

```cs
private static IEdmModel _getEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new (new DefaultAssemblyResolver());
    builder.EntitySet<ApplicationUser>("ApplicationUser");            
    builder.EntityType<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(x => x.Id); // edit: added this line
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I created a new repository, with basic code here: https://github.com/matthiasburger/ApplePie

same behaviour, reproducable with following URLs:

- `https://localhost:5001/api/testentity` : works
- `https://localhost:5001/api/testentity?$filter=id%20eq%201` : works
- `https://localhost:5001/api/testentity/1` : doesnt work
- `https://localhost:5001/api/testentity(1)` : doesnt work

Comment: `[EnableQuery][HttpGet] public IActionResult Get(long key).` I assume you use AspNetCoreOData

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes Im using AspNetCoreOData. Added `[EnableQuery]`, changed `id` to `key`... makes no difference...

Comment: You need the exact incantation. I call it an `incantation` because the docs are somewhat ... lacking, the samples in constant flux and the upcoming 8.0 version introduced breaking changes even in the recent RC. I also have `.EntityType.HasKey(h => h.Id);` in my model

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep i'm using the 8.0.0-rc.. there's no final for .net 5. so what exactly do I need? Incanation? :/ okay I'll try the HasKey ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ...still no difference...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[HttpGet][ODataRoute("ApplicationUser/{id}")]`? And else maybe add "Async" to the method, to ensude an async handler is called? If that's supported.

Comment: @JHBonarius ODataRoute is gone in v8, we need to use `HttpGet(template)`. async wont be necessary, but yeah, if this is supported I will add it as soon as I make it work. :)

Comment: [I see](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/). Hmm, got some [mcve] repo or so? edit: is your `ApiController` just deriving from `ControllerBase` with `[ApiController]`attribute?

Comment: @JHBonarius nop my `ApiController`-class derives from `ODataController`. I need to make a copy, repository is private.. i will check this and post a link asap :)

Comment: ah, found it... [then the `[ODataRouting]`attribute is redundant](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/8.0.0-rc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Routing/Controllers/ODataController.cs) not that that fixes your issue :P The `[ApiController]`attribute seems missing though...

Comment: I'm looking at your repo, but it's the full code. Will take me too much work to extract a [mcve] from that. See nothing weird at first sight. Maybe you should just start with the OData 8.0 preview sample(s) and build up from there...

Comment: @JHBonarius yeah I just took a copy for a working example :D sorry, I guess I will build up a sample and try with it. thanks anyways :)

Comment: @JHBonarius I made a minimal repo by building from scratch. https://github.com/matthiasburger/ApplePie - no copy, and same behaviour. maybe you want to take a look at it again? :D

Comment: Tomorrow. Need to sleep ;)

Comment: @JHBonarius sleep well :) thx for your help!

Comment: @MatthiasBurger can you make that repo public again? JHBonarius created a GH issue linking to it. In the meantime, I found that function routing is completely different now and all my `odata/MyEntity/MyFunction` routes are just `/MyFunction` after 8 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird, but if you change the method name "GetById" to "GetTestEntity" it works...

---

Offtopic

You can simplify your Serilog instance (removing a lot of code that's already in the host builer) by doing

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args) // sets all the configuration options right!
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        config.AddJsonFile("secrets.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true))
    .UseSerilogLogger((hostBuilderContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostBuilderContext.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()) // no output?
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => webHostBuilder
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
    );
```

The only thing you'll miss is the starting and final exception of the web host. But if there's a problem there, you'll notice anyhow.

Comment: method-name is actually really weird.. :D but yeah now it works.. - and thanks for your input about serilog :)

Comment: Speaking of `really weird`s, AspNetCoreOData filtering doesn't work in .NET 6 because of [a really weird attempt to use `Enum.TryParse`](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/44705715b79564d29cd1f1a056a71f496b12d4ef/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Query/Expressions/ExpressionBinderBase.cs#L42) : use Reflection to find a Single `TryParse` with 2 arguments. Guess what. In .NET 6 Enum has two such overloads. Kaboom

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hmm, you could file and issue [here](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues)

Comment: @JHBonarius [added with fixes](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/141) but .... that's not RC quality.

Answer (score 2):

@Matthias Burger

Let me share more detail, hope it can help.

--> Now for conventional routing:

1. You register the entity set named "ApplicationUser", so any controller named "ApplicationUserController" is considered OData controller.
2. any action in "ApplicationUserController" is potential OData methods.
3. "Get()" method meets the entity set conventional routing rule, therefore, this "Get()" action will be built two OData routes.

- ~/v{version}/ApplicationUser
- ~/v{version}/ApplicationUser/$count

4. "GetById(long id)" DOES NOT meet any built in conventional routing rule, therefore, this method doesn't have OData route build.

--> Now for the attribute routing:

5. Since you have "[ODataRouting]" decorated on your controller, any attribute routing, for example [HttpGet("ApplicationUser")] is potential OData attribute routing.
6. OData attribute routing is based on the model register. You should create the routing template starting with your route prefix, "v{version}"
7. So, if you change "[HttpGet("ApplicationUser/{id}")]" to [HttpGet("v{version}/ApplicationUser/{id}")]
   The routing should work.
8. be noted, if you add the prefix into the attribute on "Get()" method, you will get Ambiguous routes exception, because "Get()" will have OData conventional routing and attribute routing. So, avoid mixing them together.

by the way, I got 404 for you https://github.com/matthiasburger/ApplePie

and for the attribute routing, feel free to reference to:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/